# Using REPL.bat to find and replace when bracket '(' is present in phrase being replaced

Tags: batch-file, replace, find, read-eval-print-loop

Trying to use dbenham's REPL.bat to find and replace a phrase which contains a bracket '('

Need to replace `(local)` with `192.168.1.1` from the below string inside of an XML.

```
  <add name="JobRepository" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Connection Timeout=180;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=JobRepositorydb"
```

Using `type input.file |repl "(local)" "192.168.1.1" >output.file`

Produces:

```
  <add name="JobRepository" connectionString="Data Source=(192.168.1.1);Connection Timeout=180;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=JobRepositorydb"
```

But I need:

```
  <add name="JobRepository" connectionString="Data Source=192.168.1.1;Connection Timeout=180;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=JobRepositorydb"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type input.file |repl "(local)" "192.168.1.1" L >output.file
```

You need to indicate that the search string is a literal and not a regular expression.

Comment: What would be the correct syntax to simply modify the file, instead of piping to a new file (then overwriting)?

Comment: In Windows from `NT` and later you can't modify or reuse the same filename,in batch scripts.  You have to use a new filename and then `move` it to the old filename, or `del` the old file and `ren` the new one to the old filename.